# JSF 1.2 Managed bean inheritance not working

Tags: jsf, inheritance

We are inherting a base bean for all our mangagedbeans. The basebean has some common properties defined in it.
But we are not able to retrieve the value set in the Base bean. What might be the issue?

Here is how I defined.

```
BaseBean { 
    String msg; 
    // getter and setter
}
```

---

```
TestManagedBean extends BaseBean {         
    public String doAction() {
        setMsg("testMsg");     
        return "status" 
    } 
}
```

in the jsp:

```
<h:outputText value="#{testManagedBean.msg}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should work just fine. Apparently you're accessing it in the wrong instance or you are expecting that the changes will be reflected from one in other instance magically.

Make the base bean an `abstract class` and ensure that you don't register it as a `<managed-bean>`, but just the implementing class itself (when you still do so, then JSF will error when attempting to instantiate the `abstract class`). You should also reference only the implementing class by EL in the view side. I.e. don't use `#{baseBean.value}`, but just `#{concreteBean.value}`, otherwise the value will be set in the base bean instance instead of in the concrete bean instance. When you have a `#{concreteBean.submit}` as action method, the value would be still `null` this way.

---

**Update**: as per your update, although the code doesn't compile, it looks fine. The problem is caused by something else. Maybe the bean is request scoped and you've a `<redirect/>` in the navigation case which caused the bean to be garbaged and recreated on the new request?